# Ruby Watir can't find the assert method outside of the running class?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rubygems, watir, testcase

I have a class that I want to use in many test cases:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'test/unit'
require 'watir'

class Tests < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def self.Run(browser)
    #  make sure Summary of Changes exists
    assert( browser.table(:class, "summary_table_class").exists? )
    # make sure Snapshot of Change Areas exists
    assert( browser.image(:xpath, "//div[@id='report_chart_div']/img").exists?  )
    # make sure Integrated Changes table exists
    assert( browser.table(:id, 'change_table_html').exists? )
  end
end
```

However, when run in one of my test cases:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'test/unit'
require 'watir'
require 'configuration'
require 'Tests'

class TwoSCMCrossBranch < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_two_scm_cross_branch
    test_site = Constants.whatsInUrl
    puts " Step 1: go to the test site: " + test_site
    ie = Watir::IE.start(test_site)

    Tests.Run(ie)

  end
end
```

I get the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `assert' for Tests:Class
    C:/p4/dev/webToolKit/test/webapps/WhatsIn/ruby-tests/Tests.rb:8:in `Run'
```

What's missing? Thanks!

Comment: I have never ran a test inside of a test. I can see what you are trying to do. Maybe you just put the asserts in the parent test and don't have the child?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assert() is an instance method on TestCase so would only be available to instances of Tests. You are calling it inside a class method so Ruby is looking for a class method in Tests which doesn't exist.

A better way to do this is to make Tests a module and the Run method an instance method:

```
module Tests
  def Run(browser)
    ...
  end
end
```

Then include the Tests module in your test class:

```
class TwoSCMCrossBranch < Test::Unit::TestCase
  include Tests

  def test_two_scm_cross_branch
    test_site = Constants.whatsInUrl
    puts " Step 1: go to the test site: " + test_site
    ie = Watir::IE.start(test_site)

    Run(ie)
  end
end
```

which will make the Run method available to the test and Run() will find the assert() method in the test class.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth a try to remove the `asserts` all together, and just use `.exists?`.

Comment: assert is the key to TestCase. without it, it will error saying there are no assertions :(